# Adapted Cantrip vs Bloodline cantrip

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e

You cannot swap out Bloodline spells (CRB 190) using the usual method for changing your spells:

> Swapping Spells In Your Repertoire
> As you gain new spells in your spell repertoire, you might want to replace some of the spells you previously learned. [...] This spell can be a cantrip, but **you can't swap out bloodline spells**

Adapted Cantrip seems different:

> Choose one cantrip from a magical tradition other than your own. If you have a spell repertoire [...], **replace one of the cantrips you know** [...] with the chosen spell.

Can I use this feat to circumvent the limitation, and take something useful instead of the awful Bloodline cantrip?

---

Edit 2022-09-10: I just realized the Bloodline Spells are your Focus Spells. So I want to swap out *Granted Spells*, which is not forbidden.
However, I guess the developers meant Granted Spells in the Swapping sections, as those are the cantrips and slotted spells you could at least *theoretically* swap.

Comment: Which bloodline are you referring to, where you find the bloodline cantrip so objectionable?

Comment: @BenBarden I do not think it makes any difference for the answer, but Chill Touch and Light very much depend on your build, while Produce Flame, Tanglefoot and _Acid Splash especially_ are just weak.

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a couple of days, and I don't know if there's going to be a clear-cut answer. Even the generic specific trumps general guidance is fairly ambiguous, since both are about as equally specific. As a GM, I'd say no, but that's more for thematic reasons than anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The section you reference, ["Swapping Spells in Your Repertoire" from PF2CR#193](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=11) does not specify how you cannot swap out bloodline spells, only that you cannot do it.  Immediately after, it also defines another instance where you might be able to swap the spell...

> You can also swap out spells by retraining during downtime.

To me, this means that the statement, "This spell can be a cantrip, but you can’t swap out bloodline spells," applies to the section "Swapping Spells in Your Repertoire," as a general rule for swapping out spells. Additionally, my quote above references the [Retraining heading on PF2CR#481](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=475), which states, "Your GM determines whether you can get proper training or whether something can be retrained at all," meaning that your GM has the final call.  It also states "...a sorcerer can retrain their bloodline only in extraordinary circumstances."  Given all of that, were I the GM, under less-than-extraordinary circumstances, I would say, "no, you can't retrain it," and the very max I would allow (even under extraordinary circumstances) without a full bloodline change would require it to be of the same spell list/tradition.

Logically, I also feel like the nature of the Sorcerer (and bloodlines) is that they are part of your very essence, flowing through you.

For me, the combination of role-playing-nope and logic-nope make a pretty hard "nope."  Hope this helps.

Comment: My apologies @ESCE, and thanks for the SRD edits.  If I ever forget again, feel free to call me out on it and I'll hook it up.

Comment: no worries :) adding links actually makes me read rules that I'd otherwise just skim over, so I don't mind doing it, and it's certainly _not_ a requirement to have your answers or questions linked to the SRD!